# How to create csv file in Arabic Language?

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to create CSV file column in Arabic language, I am using resource bundle to get the value from properties file and it is able to get value in Arabic but after creation of file the column name is displaying like **"?????????????"** instead of Arabic. Please help me to resolve this problem.

I am using below code:

```
public static void downloadCSVForReconcilationData(String downloadStr,HttpServletResponse response,String reportName) throws IOException{

    //response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\""+"BillingTrxReport.csv"+"\"");
    response.setContentType ("application/x-csv");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\""+reportName+".csv"+"\";");
    //response.setHeader("application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=Cp1256","attachment; filename=\""+reportName+".csv"+"\";");// khushwant Patidar
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=Cp1256");// khushwant Patidar
    response.setContentLength((int) downloadStr.length());

try{
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out);
    BufferedWriter bufw=new BufferedWriter(pw);
    //BufferedOutputStream outBuf = new BufferedOutputStream(out);

    bufw.write(downloadStr);
    bufw.close();
    pw.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    }catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        throw ioe;
    }
}
```

Comment: The file is correctly encoaded but arabic language is not displaying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use CP1256 in content-type you must use the same when creation the file with [java.io.PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29).

I suggest:

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
PrintStream  ps  = new PrintStream( out, true, "CP1256" );
ps.println( downloadStr );
ps.close();
```

[It's not necessary to flush and close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#close%28%29) the out variable.

Comment: Please edit your question to post Java code. I'll edit it in my answer to show you

Comment: I have tried that one but compile time error is coming, The error are --> The Constructor PrintWriter(OutputStream , String ) is Undefined.

Comment: I am using PrintWriter instead of PrintStream. Shall I change in PrintStream?

Comment: I've edited the code to add the autoflush argument. Read the Javacdoc.